# Back button with nested states in Angular Router

Tags: angularjs, back-button, angular-ui, angularjs-routing, angular-routing

I have an AngularJS application that makes use of the new, state-based [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I have three different views in my application, where one is a top-level views, and the other two are nested ones.

The structure basically is as follows:

```
/ => Top-level view
/foo => Abstract view, loads a view that contains a ui-view placeholder
/foo/bar => View for the placeholder
/foo/baz => View for the placeholder
```

The router is set up as following:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  'use strict';

  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/bar', '/foo/bar')
    .otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
        '': {
          controller: 'homeController',
          templateUrl: '/home/homeLayout.html',
        },
        'firstHomeView@home': {
          templateUrl: '/home/firstHomeView.html'
        },
        'secondHomeView@home': {
          templateUrl: '/homme/secondHomeView.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('foo', {
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: '/foo/fooLayout.html',
      controller: 'fooController'
    })
    .state('foo.bar', {
      url: '/foo/bar',
      templateUrl: '/foo/barView.html',
      controller: 'barController'
    })
    .state('foo.baz', {
      url: '/foo/baz',
      templateUrl: '/foo/bazView.html',
      controller: 'bazController'
    });
```

The problem is, that basically everything works as expected when you click around or manually type in urls, but that it does not work when using the back / forward buttons of the browser.

E.g., is you go to `/foo`, you are taken to `/foo/bar`, as expected. When you then click on a link to go to `/foo/baz`, everything is fine. Then click a link that takes you to `/`, and everything is still fine.

If you now hit the back button, you are taken back to `/foo/baz` (which is correct), but only the `/foo/fooLayout.html` view is rendered, not its sub-view `/foo/bazView.html`. The strange thing is now that if you hit the back button again, you are taken to `/foo/bar` *and it renders correctly, including its subview*! It seems as if nested views weren't recognized when using the back button, at least, if you enter an abstract view at the same time.

`$locationProvider.html5Mode` is not enabled, but enabling it doesn't make any difference.

I am using AngularJS 1.0.5 and ui-router 0.0.1-2013-03-20.

Any ideas what might cause this issue, and how I might solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the error: In the view `fooLayout.html` I was using `ng-view` instead of `ui-view`. Once I changed that, everything was fine :-)

Comment: glad you found the solution on the next day.. :)